# How to get tag names in xml using simple xml object

Tags: php

Hi I have following simple xml object:

```
[ad] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [title] => <b>Title: Mysql 1</b>
                [abstract] => Abstract: Mysql 1
                [url] => www.Mysql.com
                [rurl] => http://sample/xtrack.php?rurldata=yes
                [iurl] => http://sample.com/
                [bid] => 0.0880
            )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [title] => <b>Title: Mysql 2</b>
                [abstract] => Abstract: Mysql 2
                [url] => www.Mysql.com
                [rurl] => http://sample/xtrack.php?rurldata=yes
                [iurl] => http://sample.com/
                [bid] => 0.1980
            )
    )
```

I want to create an array from this. I am trying in foreach like this

```
foreach($xmlString->ad as $key){
        foreach($key as $key2 => $val2){
             $adData[$counter][$key2] = $val2;
        }
            $counter++;
}
```

But I get a structure like this:

```
 Array
  (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => <b>Title: Mysql 1</b>
            )

        [abstract] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => Abstract: Mysql 1
            )

        [url] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => www.Mysql.com
            )

        [rurl] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => http://sample/xtrack.php?rurldata=yes
            )

        [iurl] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => http://sample.com/
            )

        [bid] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => 0.0880
            )

    )
    .
    .
    .So on
```

now I know that $key2 is an object. How can i retrieve only tag name of that ? How to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bellow example may helps you..

XML File: student.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <students>
      <student>
        <name>Hearaman</name>
        <age>24</age>
        <email>hearaman.dev@gmail.com</email>
        <address>Bangalore, India</address>
     </student>
 </students>
```

PHP Code:

```
    <?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("student.xml");

    echo "Parent Tag = ". $xml->getName() . "<br />";

    foreach($xml->children()->children() as $child)
      {
      echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get the name using the [`SimpleXmlEmement::getName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php) method

```
foreach($xmlString->ad as $key){
   echo $key->getName() . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: if I do this:  

`$adData[$counter][$key2->getName()] = $val2;`  

I get error:  

`Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in`  

But it is an object

Comment: @Shades88: the error message state that you are trying to use a non object as object, are you sure `$key2` is set properly

Comment: ohhh I get it now. $key2 is a string. But $val2 that I get is an object. Don't understand what is going on here

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($xmlString->children() as $child)
{
    $tagsArr[] = $child->getName();
}
```

Comment: Please provide extra information in addition to your code (even if this might already answer the question). Beginners might not understand your code without some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result=array();
foreach($add as $key=>$val){
    $result[]['title'] = (string)$add[$key]->title;
    $result[]['abstract'] = (string)$add[$key]->abstract;
    $result[]['url'] = (string)$add[$key]->url;
    $result[]['rurl'] = (string)$add[$key]->rurl;
    $result[:]['iurl'] = (string)$add[$key]->iurl;
    $result[]['bid'] = (string)$add[$key]->bid;
}
```

Comment: I know, I could do this. But I am avoiding hardcoding of index names. As this function I want to be as generalised as possible